# How to make the imagebox not to visible when it donot have image in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, image, controls

I am using webservice to load the image to the imagebox from the database.
If the DB do not have any image it show the image box with no-image pic.But i want to make the image box not to visible when it do not have an image

Below is the code i used to load image

```
MyImg.ImageUrl = @"~/ShowImage.ashx?id=" + MyID;
```

Thanks in advance for your replies..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like:

```
if (DoesImageExist(MyID)) {
    MyImg.ImageUrl = @"~/ShowImage.ashx?id=" + MyID;
    // Just in case we hid the image during the previous request
    // and ViewState is enabled:
    MyImg.Visible = true;
} else {
    MyImg.Visible = false;
}
```

Comment: But MyID is just the userid that i pass it as a Query string value to the webservice..I am talking about the null value returned from the webservice

Comment: @Dhamu, so how do you know if the image exists or not? Does your `ShowImage.ashx` handler return `404` in that case?

Comment: @Dhamu, well then, your best bet is to perform a database query in your server-side code (the `DoesImageExist()` call in my updated answer) so you can avoid rendering the image if it doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

When your handler is called, it's too late to make the control invisible.

What you can do however is (when the database returns no image) to then return some fixed single white (or transparent) pixel image. The `<img>` tag is still on the page, but the user doesn't see an "image not available" error.

The only other way is to check whether data is available (no need to get the complete image, just that it's there) when you render the control, so you can make it invisible when there is no image.